# Why the data base is not populated even after successful form rendering and submission of form in my django app?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am beginner in django and making a simple Book registration form to populate sql3 database. I think i did everything right, and the the form is rendering properly and when hit submit it even sends POST request but database don't get populated. I researched on this problem my entire weekend, went to bootstrap documentation and also studied about is_valid() function. It shows error like "

book_name

This field is required.

".
I don't know how to deal with it and what should i do??
My models.py

````
from django.db import models
class Book(models.Model):
    #Create your models here
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    page =models.CharField(max_length=20)
    authors =models.CharField(max_length=200)
    registration = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_name
```
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . models import Book
from .forms import BookForm
def say_hello(request):
    if(request.method=="POST"):
        #if Post request is made :do something
        form = BookForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("New Book Object is created")
            #Book.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
            form.save()
        else:

            print(form.errors)
            print("Invalid Form data")

        return render(request,'join.html',{})
        #Add all things posted to the Bookform

    else:
        #otherwise just reder a normal web page
        return render(request,'join.html',{})
def index(request):
    all_books=Book.objects.all
    return render(request,'index.html',{'all':all_books})
# Create your views here.
```


forms.py
```
from django import forms
from . models import Book
#To post data to the datbase obtained from form
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['book_name','authors','page','registration']

```
    

join.html
```
{%  extends 'base.html' %}<!-- We are including bootstrap loaded base.html file-->
{% block content %}

    <h1>    Register Your Favorite Book
        </h1>
    <p>
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'hello' %}"> <!-- It says that Call view function respective to 'hello url -->
    {% csrf_token  %} <!-- IT's for security from hacker-->
        <p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Book Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="book_name" placeholder="Enter Book Name",name="book_name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="authors_name">Authors</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author_name" placeholder="Authors' Name" name="authors">
  </div>
         <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Pages">No. Of Pages</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="page_no" placeholder="No. of Pages" name="page">
              <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Registration">Registration No</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reg_no" placeholder="Book Registration No" name="registration">
  </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
    </p>
    </body>
{% endblock %}```
````

Comment: It shows error like `<ul class="errorlist"><li>book_name<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
` I tried everything but don't understand what is causing this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `book_name` is not well processed, because you have comma inside `name` attribute:

```
placeholder="Enter Book Name",name="book_name"
```

Another thing is form data in template is not the same that `BookForm` is expecting.

To do it right way, you should add your form as a context in `GET` part:

```
else:
    # otherwise just reder a normal web page
    return render(request, 'join.html', {'form': BookForm()})
```

Then in template just do this:

```
{{ form }}
```

You can check what `id` and `name` attributes are automatically created (which are needed later for `BookForm` in `POST` part. Which you should also provide then. Basically it might look like this:

```
def say_hello(request):
    if request.method == "POST":   # don't use parenthesis for if statement, it's redundant in Python :)
        form = BookForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
        else:
            ...
    elif request.method == "GET":
        form = BookForm()
        ...
    return render(request, 'join.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried "GET" inplace of POST request and find out that it is still not entering data to database. I tried what you have said and i found that i am getting the error because the POST or GET request my app is getting contains 'Csrfmiddlewaretoken'in place of 'book_name' attribute while all other attributes are specified by desired values. And due to this it is throwing error like`<ul class="errorlist"><li>book_name<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li>`.

Comment: My post request.POST looks something like this `<QueryDict: <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['ppquzxISxBgv0L2lyDsNEqQPekCmoUFf0n9NskVSiezIG0LryTtYKv5LpjQk9Ywl'], 'authors': ['Paulo Cohelho'], 'page': ['500'], 'registration': ['BGH56809']}>
`. And i don't know how to fix it. What is causing my book_name field being missing. I just can't figured it out. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' is added by default, it's good that it is there. If you did what I have told you, you should not have that error. I think the comma right before `name` might be the problem then: `placeholder="Enter Book Name",name="book_name"`

Comment: Thanks @NixonSparrow You are a life saver. One damn comma ruined my entire weekend.